# ReduxForm: Marking an FieldArray item for deletion?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux-form

When editing a `FieldArray` containing data that's already saved, I want the delete button to just add the attribute `_destroy: true` to the object. From there, when I structure my PUT to the API, I'll instruct that record to be destroyed.

In the onClick for delete, I tried:

```
(e) => {
  const objectToDestroy = { ...fields.get(e.target.value), _destroy: true };

  // If ID exists, we need to PUT a delete, else we can just remove from the list

  fields.remove(e.target.value)
  if (objectToDestroy.id) fields.insert(e.target.value, objectToDestroy)
}
```

And this works, in terms of what I see in the store. So I tried to reflect this in the UI by making the "deleted" fields disappear. Here's the function I made for determining whether to render a field that's the `FieldArray` is iterating over:

```
const isRowVisible = (index) => {
  return !fields.get(index)._destroy;
}
```

When I clicked the first destroy button, the item disappear. But when I clicked a second, it did not disappear until I focused on a form element (to force a re-render of the form).

Is there a better way to approach this whole thing that I'm missing? Or perhaps something I'm doing wrong?

EDIT:

I added the field `_destroy` to the form:

```
<Field name={`${member}._destroy`} component="input" />
```

And here's a gif to help visualize the problem:

[image: Visualization]